# Notifications appear twice in iOS9

Tags: objective-c, notifications, ios9

I have the following codes in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in appDelegate.

```
if([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings =   [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should try this in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

Comment: still getting notifications twice. how does isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications make a difference?